# How to make this formula increment starting from 1 and not 0?

Tags: excel

So I have this function `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2))&"*")` that counts image position in 1 row, and increments by 1 if the sku remains the same, once sku changes it *should* reset to 1 but is going 0. I'm sure it's an easy fix but I see no place to indicate starting index of 1.

Data looks like this (you can see it also repeats 0 2 times, for some reason)

[image]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: You're using a function that is counting the number of times a string value occurs in a cell/cell range. You are searching for `_`, and in your first two rows of the screen shot, it's 0 times, so shows a zero. It appears the function is working as designed. You likely copied this forumla to all cells in the second visible column of the screen shot. I image the built-in copy when dragging changed the reference cells, because you're getting different values each row. Maybe you should state what and why, because I think COUNTIF() isn't the "how".

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm realizing one of the VBA scripts I'm using is assigning the seoncd image (i.e. 17651_2) as the first image, that's fine, I just need my script to look for either that (suffix of _2.jpg) or 17651.jpg by itself with no underscore (for other images) and start 1 there, not 0. And then reset when the sku changes.

Comment: it might help more if you state "what" you are trying to do, at the real requirement level. I understand you are trying to determine a sequence number by file name, but what are you going to *do* with that? Just making sure this isn't an XY Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The problem with your formula is that you only check for "_". But you can also have "-" and no symbols. Here, in fact, you get errors.
Also in your formula you take the entire URL. But if such characters are encountered earlier in the URL, then everything will also break.

### **I sketched a quick formula that will work correctly**

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2, "*"&
    IFERROR(
        LEFT( LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1)), FIND(".", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1))) -1),FIND("-", LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1)), FIND(".", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1))) -1) )-1),
        IFERROR(
            LEFT( LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1)), FIND(".", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1))) -1),FIND("_", LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1)), FIND(".", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1))) -1) )-1),
            LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1)), FIND(".", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1))) -1)
        )
    )
&"*")
```

### **What is happening here, laid out step by step:**

1. We get the name of the file. That is, we discard part of the URL: https://someurl.com/Sarreid/

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))),1 ))
// Return: 17651-2.jpg
```

2. Trim the file extension:

```
=LEFT(C2, FIND("., C2) -1)
// Return: 17651-2
```

3. We get the SKU of the file:

```
=IFERROR(
     LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2)-1),
     IFERROR(
         LEFT(D2,FIND("_",D2)-1),
         D2
     )
)
// Return: 17651
```

4. We count the number of identical SKUs:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2, "*"&E2&"*")
// Return: 1, 2, 3...
```

### You can break these steps down into columns to get the results incrementally.

> - Step 1: to Column "C"
> - Step 2: to Column "D"
> - Step 3: to Column "E"
> - Step 4: to Column "F"